# Optimization under l-inf norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm trying to find good bounds for optimizing $A$ under following constraint:

$max_{{\left\|u\right\|}_{\infty}\le 1}{\quad u^T A u}$

Not really sure how to approach it but I guess a condition on some norm of A or its trace would be great.